# JAVA Time related challenge after upgraded to WL 12C & Java 1.8

Tags: java, time

Facing issue with this piece of code.

```
public static Date makeDate(Date date, Time time) {
    if (date == null) {
        return time;
    }
    if (time == null) {
        return date;
    }

    Calendar theTime = new GregorianCalendar();
    theTime.setTime(time);
    int timeOffset = 0;
    try {
        timeOffset = theTime.get(theTime.ZONE_OFFSET);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    }
    return new Date(date.getTime() + time.getTime() + timeOffset);
}
```

As you see after upgrade same code is doubling the time

What could be possible cause for this after upgrade?
What is this fix for this issue?

Comment: Below update was done .
 OLD Version Upgraded to Version
OS Version Sun Solaris 10 Sun Solaris 10
Status for the script which call the Package Works fine Desired updates on the Data Base are not happening
Java Version Java ver 1.7 Java ver 1.8 (1.8.0_181)
WebLogic Version WebLogic 11g (10.3.6) WebLogic 12c (12.2.1.3)
Oracle DB Version 11.2 11.2
Server Date time of 31-Oct-2018 07:35:10
Problem we are facing with the upgrade => Outcome is: 31-Oct-2018 07:35:10 Outcome is: 31-Oct-2018 15:10:20
(07:35:10 + 07:35:10 = 15:10:20)

Comment: `new Date(date.getTime() + time.getTime() + timeOffset)` - that's novel - why `time + time`? Since you're using Java 8, why not make use of the new date time API?

Comment: @MadProgrammer - Thank you so much for quick response, Which new API you are talking about ? Also why the above code is causing problem. Any help will be much appreciated .

Comment: [Java Date and Time classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/datetime.html) which should be used over `java.util.Date` and `Calendar` based APIs